# JSON key:values changes after upgrading jersey from 2.17 to 2.35

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I have an web application which is currently on jersey-2.16. After I upgrade it to jersey-2.35 I see the JSON responses(JSON key to be specific) is getting capitalized.

JSON response in jesrsey-2.17

```
{
"Key1":"value1"
"Key2":"value2"
"Key3":"value3"
}
```

JSON response in jesrsey-2.35

```
{
"KEY1":"value1"
"KEY2":"value2"
"KEY3":"value3"
}
```

To solve this issue, I had to change my setters and rename them as follows:

`setKEY1() to setKey1()` and similary to all other setters.

I am unable to understand how changing name of setter Method is changing the JSON response. Is it some property that jersey uses based on which the JSON response/request changes?

Comment: Different providers is being used. That's the only thing I can think

Comment: What provider do you use? The default in Jersey 2.17 is Moxy, the default in 2.35 is JSON-B/Yasson. Or maybe you use Jackson?

Comment: Sorry, i am new to this, I tried to search on how to figure out the provider i am using, is there any way i can find out the provider i am using? I do not have any @Provider annotation in the class file where the setter is present.  This is not an maven project, this project is built using Apache ant.

Comment: @jan.supol I checked the web.xml , i do not have any jackson related property in <init-param>

Comment: With Ant, it depends on what jars you have on your classpath.

Comment: @jan.supol I have jars related to jersey-2.35 , jackson, jakarta, osgi. I can share all the jars if its required for clarity, just that there are quite a lot in number. I have referred this site eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey/download.html and added all the required dependencies for jersey-2.35

Comment: So it looks like Jackson then. Do you use the same version of Jackson for 2.17 and 2.35?

Comment: @jan.supol Yes, Jackson has not been update, what version should i be using with jersey-2.35?

Comment: 2.35 is using Jackson 2.13.x. Jackson can be configured via [ContextResolver](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson). So you can set `ObjectMapper#setPropertyNamingStrategy` to configure the key name with camel-case.

Comment: The provider depends on the runtime classpath, i.e. what environment / application server it runs at, such as Payara which provides the dependencies. Or do you run on a Servlet Container such as Tomcat, where you need to provide your own dependencies for Jersey?

Comment: @jan.supol In maven repository, i see jersey-media-jackson has compile dependencies with jackson with minimum version 2.12.2 is it not the right version to use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243328/discussion-between-yuhubug-and-jan-supol).